# fetch data based on similar value

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

I have two table table1 and table2.

table1 have:

```
code   name
 10     ABC
 11     DEF
 12     FGH
```

table2 have:

```
code1  code2   code3      Buyer    
10       11      12        AAA        
12       11      10        BBB       
11       12      10        CCC
```

Now, i want to make SQL query that fetch code1, code2, code3, buyer and name of code1, code2 and code3..
My SQL query is:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.code, t2.issued, t2.balance 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.code = t2.code;
```

using this SQL query, name is not fetching based on every code. Output comes wrong.
I want output like {code1=10, name=ABC, code2=11, name=DEF, code3=12, name=FGH, buyer=AAA}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to join the table multiple times with different alias names

```
SELECT t2.code, t2.issued, t2.balance,
       tname1.name as code1_name,
       tname2.name as code2_name,
       tname3.name as code3_name
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 tname1 WHERE tname1.code = t2.code1
JOIN table1 tname2 WHERE tname2.code = t2.code2
JOIN table1 tname3 WHERE tname3.code = t2.code3
```

Answer (score 1):

You surely require 3 joins as below for code c1,c2,c3 names respectively.

```
         Select code1,c1.name,code2
        ,c2.name,code3,c3.name,buyer
        from table2,
        table1 c1,table1 c2,table1 c3 where 
        c1.code=code1 and c2.code=code2 and 
        c3.code=code3
```